# Structure multiple binominal columns to one column

Tags: r, database, dplyr, data.table, format

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
X1  X2     X3
Red NA     NA
NA  Blue   NA
NA  Green  NA 
NA  NA     Red
NA  Yellow NA
NA  NA     Blue
```

And I need to convert in this form:

```
   Result
   Red
   Blue
   Green
   Red
   Yellow
   Blue
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: coalesce(X1,X2,X3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `max.col`

```
data.frame(Result = df1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 
          max.col(!is.na(df1), 'first'))])
```

-output

```
#  Result
#1    Red
#2   Blue
#3  Green
#4    Red
#5 Yellow
#6   Blue
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c("Red", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c(NA, 
"Blue", "Green", NA, "Yellow", NA), X3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Red", 
NA, "Blue")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a random df and convert:

```
x <- sample(c(NA, NA, 'red', 'green', 'blue'), 12, replace = TRUE)
m <- matrix(x, ncol = 3)
df <- as.data.frame(m)

result <- unlist(t(df)) #transpose of dataframe to order result by row
result <- result[!is.na(result)]
result <- as.data.frame(result)
result
  result
1  green
2   blue
3    red
4  green
5    red
6   blue
7   blue
8   blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a base R option

```
> data.frame(result = df[!is.na(df)])
  result
1    Red
2   Blue
3  Green
4 Yellow
5    Red
6   Blue
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(X1 = c("Red", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c(NA, 
"Blue", "Green", NA, "Yellow", NA), X3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Red",
NA, "Blue")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```